# How can you store lists of Items in Flutter

Tags: flutter, sqflite

How could you store something like that even when the app is closed in Flutter:

```
Class myList {
    String id;
    List<Item> list;
}

Class Item{
    //Many property’s
}
```

I thought maybe I could do that with "sqflite", a flutter dependency, but I have no Idea how I could store there this List<Item>. Do you have any idea?

Btw: I need multiple of these "myList" instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store it using sqflite,[hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) or shared preferences.Try to save it under flutter [shared preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences). These are two methods that you can use.

Using shared preferences
1)First create a shared preference instance

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

Then save the relevant data type.here you need to put a object list so add the list and convert it to the String using jsonEncode.

```
Map<String,List<Item>> map={mylist.id: mylist.list};
prefs.setString("itemList", json.encode(map));
```

Then you can retrieve data like this

```
Map<String,List<Item>> map=json.decode(prefs.getString("itemList")).asMap();
```

---

2)Using Hive
First Create the hive databse.you can put any name here

```
var box = Hive.box('myBox');
```

Then add the object in to that database

```
var myList = myList()
..id = your id here
..list = add list here;

var name = box.add(myList);
```

You can get anywhere this data list.

```
print(box.getAt(0));
```

Comment: Is there any reason why people say "don't store large amounts of data in shared preferences"? I mean the option with shared preferences looks easier, but I have to store probably almost 10 of these Lists with contains 3-6 of my Items. Is that a problem for shared preferences ?

Comment: yes consider the data amount when using the shared preferences. Think Hive is the best solution.See the documentation in pub.dev for hive.

Comment: Okay, that means you would say up to 60 of these Items (wich all have 5 String or Int propertys) is too much for shared preferences, or at least hive would be much better?

Comment: It's not get error.Using large amount data in shared preference get you some performance issues. Hive would be much better.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) package. It is a lightweight local storage passage and it is a good idea to use hive because it has better benchmarks for reading and writes. You can search for the tutorial for the hive. or just read the documentation.